# How can I limit lua possibilities (calling OS functions, modules, etc.)

Tags: lua

I am using Lua as a script language inside my C application.

It suits me well, but I can't understand how can I limit Lua not to call system functions, include other modules, etc.

I want Lua to be able to call only functions that are allowed by me, because user can do all kind of bad things with full Lua + Lua modules power.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Simple Sandbox on the Lua-users wiki: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes

Related SO discussions:

- [Is there anyway to avoid this security issue in Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325323/is-there-anyway-to-avoid-this-security-issue-in-lua)
- [How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox)
- [How to execute an untrusted Lua file in its own environment from the C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444312/how-to-execute-an-untrusted-lua-file-in-its-own-environment-from-the-c-api)

Answer (score 2):

Sandbox is the term you're looking for. In a nutshell, only export to Lua the functions you want the users to call. It's that simple, really.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by not loading the `os` or `package` modules. Rather than using `luaL_openlibs`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15160350/1205758).