# How do I disable the risky functions in lua the easiest way possible?

Tags: c++, security, lua

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I limit lua possibilities (calling OS functions, modules, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627954/how-can-i-limit-lua-possibilities-calling-os-functions-modules-etc)
>   [How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox)

```
luaL_openlibs(m_pState);
```

I use this function to load all the libs.I would like to skip all the dangerous libs like IO but I just cant find any documentation on how to disable a lib.

How do I disable certain libs? Are there more dangerous libs that can gain the script access to the system?

Comment: There are a number of SO questions on this already. For example,  [How can I create a secure Lua sandbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224708/how-can-i-create-a-secure-lua-sandbox) and [How can I limit lua possibilities (calling OS functions, modules, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627954/how-can-i-limit-lua-possibilities-calling-os-functions-modules-etc). [See here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) as well

Answer (score 4):

Add a copy of `linit.c` to your project and remove any libraries that you deem dangerous. To remove individual functions, set them to nil. See also the [source](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#demo) of the [Lua demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).